# Error loading module file () - Wordpress

Tags: upgrade

I have just upgraded a CiviCRM install on Wordpress. Went from Civi 4.5x to 4.6.5. The site uses L10n (EN / FR).

I had two error messages when I first finished the upgrade. One was:

"civicrm Unknown extension: net.ourpowerbase.sumfields"

That one seems to have resolved itself.

The other is: 
"Error loading module file (). Please restore the file or disable the module."

This error appears both in the admin area of CiviCRM and on the front end where profile forms are used.

I have no idea where to start looking to fix this! I found one post about drupal, but that didn't help.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This typically happens when either a) an extension is deleted, or b) the location of the extension changes.

First, make the easy fix.  Go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Cleanup Caches and Update Paths**.  Press "Clear Caches", and reload the page TWICE.  Hopefully that fixes the error.  If not - check that page and make sure the paths are 100% correct.

If that doesn't work, go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Manage Extensions** and look for anything amiss.  Take special note of missing extensions - see if they're actually missing in the file system.

This should get you all cleaned up, or at least on the right track!

Comment: Thank you! Going into managing extensions did the trick. It was the Summary Field extension that hasn't been updated to run on 4.6.x. Ended up having to uninstall the thing.

Comment: Glad to hear your problem is solved.  That said - I DO run Summary Fields on multiple 4.6 sites without issue, so hopefully you can reinstall if needed.

Comment: I am running into the same problem after moving a site to dev and I have the same issue. I have checked all the paths and that did not work.  I think I might need to do something like /**
*
*$civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['extensionsDir'] = '/home/site/www/sites/default/files/civicrm/extend/';
*
*/ - but that gave me a WSOD.

Answer (score 2):

I had the "Error loading module" issue with Civi 5.x/Joomla 3.8x. This message was appearing before most front-end content. The suggestions above led me to disable then re-enable extensions that had been installed with git clone (namely Mosaico 2.0b & related). This cured the problem.